# Asset pipeline doesn't compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, asset-pipeline

I have an application that has three different CSS themes and each of those themes has a dozen or so color schemes. Everything works fine in development but the asset pipeline is giving me some odd issues.

Essentially I have several files like this

```
/themes
  /cool-theme
    _theme.scss
    /color-schemes
      red.scss
```

The idea is I precompile all the *.scss files except the partials (starting with the underscore) since they are included in the SASS. So I am using this code:

```
stylesheets_directory = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets"
config.assets.precompile += Dir.glob("#{stylesheets_directory}/**/*.scss").
                            map{|f| f[stylesheets_directory.size+1..-1]}.
                            select do |file|
                            if config.assets.precompile.include?(file)
                              puts "Already have #{file}"
                              false
                            elsif File.basename(file)[0...1] == "_"
                              puts "Partial detected #{file}"
                              false
                            else
                              puts "Including #{file}"
                              true
                            end
                          end
```

The code runs fine and shows an output I expect during assets:precompile. Excludes everything it should and includes everything it should.

The problem is the /public/assets directory never contains the css files for anything other then application.css. It's missing red.css, blue.css, etc...

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the pipeline works for Javascript files and stylesheets is it's only going to precompile an `application.js` and `application.css` file for you by default.
This is why you have tried to append more assets to the `config.assets.precompile` Array. You're on the right track, but have made a few mistakes.

#### The File Extension

You need to rename

```
app/assets/stylesheets/themes/cool-theme/color-schemes/red.scss
```

to

```
app/assets/stylesheets/themes/cool-theme/color-schemes/red.css.scss
```

This tells the pipeline that you want this to be a `.css` file when it's finished compiling.

#### The Asset Path

Currently you're appending a path like

```
/Path/To/Your/app/assets/stylesheets/themes/cool-theme/color-schemes/red.scss
```

to the `config.assets.precompile` Array. Instead you need to be passing a path in this format

```
themes/cool-theme/color-schemes/red.css
```

When you precompile your assets you'll see a new `themes` folder created inside `public/assets/` containing the rest of your directory tree, complete with a compiled `red.css` file.

---

I'll leave fixing your code for appending paths to the `config.assets.precompile` up to you as you seem more than capable of making the necessary changes outlined above.